# Is that possible to restore a SQL server 2016 backup with different default language?

Tags: sql-server

In our old server we have a MSSQL server 2012 with the German language as its default language. In our new server, we would like to install MSSQL server 2016 with the English language as its default language and then we want to migrate to the new server. Is that possible to restore the sql2012 backup (defualt language: German) on the new Sql server 2016?
I could not find anything against this strategy in Internet, but before buying the ISO file, I would like to be sure if this strategy works.
I appreciate for any help.

Comment: Yes. When you tried this (as I see no reason why you wouldn't have done before asking this) what error did you get?

Comment: A database doesn't have a "default language", it has a collation. You can't buy (or need to buy) a SQL Server 2016 ISO, it's already out of support. The oldest version still in mainstream support is SQL Server 2017. You can download the Developer Edition for free and test restores there. Developer Edition has all the features Enterprise has, without a license to use in production

Comment: When you say language are you referring to the UI or the collation? You can have databases with different collations on the same server. The UI language only applies to the client tools or services, and most of them are available as separate downloads that *aren't* affected by the server or database. SSMS is a separate fre download for example. SSRS is a separate download as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite SQL Server supports all languages that are supported by Windows operating systems, localized versions of SQL Server can only be upgraded to localized versions of the same language, and cannot be upgraded to the English-language version. Visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/local-language-versions-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16. This is why I was concerning if restoring a database in a different language of sql server is possible and then I asked this question here.

As I tested this senario, I could create a backup using DE Sql server 2012 and then restore it in En SQL server 2016 (both standard edition). Upgrading the database version was also successful. I wanted to share the result here, perhaps this may help some one at future.